# Python - Finding contours of different colors on an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have the following image: 
[image]

I used the following code to outline all the round blobs in this image using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('im.jpg')

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,200,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(im,contours,-1,(0,0,255),1)

#(B,G,R)

cv2.imshow('image',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And it produces this image:
[image]

Which is great for the first step. But I'm having a really hard time drawing a different colored outline for the blue colored blobs. I tried using multiple contours:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('im.jpg')

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,200,255,0)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(imgray,130,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours2, hierarchy2 = cv2.findContours(thresh2,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(im,contours,-1,(0,0,255),1)
cv2.drawContours(im,contours2,-1,(0,255,0),1)

#(B,G,R)

cv2.imshow('image',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and the image comes out like this: 
[image]

The first problem with this approach is the fact that it doesn't accurately only outline the blue blobs. Moreover, the sensitivity rating in the `threshold` function would have to be modified for each image depending on lighting, etc. Is there a smoother way to do this?

Comment: it wouldn't hurt if you'd read something about color image processing...

Comment: I did, that's how I got this far. But id  like some help progressing.

Comment: did you skip the part on hue by any chance? :D  see headcrabs answer. make sure you understand RGB, HSV and other standard color spaces if you want to do color image processing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("bluepink.jpg")
imghsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
mask_blue = cv2.inRange(imghsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask_blue, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
im = np.copy(img)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
cv2.imwrite("contours_blue.png", im)
```

[image]

Not ideal, but there seem to be no false positives. And you can probably improve it by adding another near-black color range (as really dark color is only present inside those bluish blobs). Maybe with some additional dilate-eroding, it never hurts to dilate-erode.