# Find and fill contour of an image which has different colors

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, image-segmentation

I saw this answer: [Python - Finding contours of different colors on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095734/python-finding-contours-of-different-colors-on-an-image) but in my case, it's becoming difficult to know different color thresholds because of varying brightness in images

I have few plant images where I am trying to segment the plant. Some plants have good shape and color but some have brownish tint to the leaves. How should I make a good segmentation of these images using opencv. I first thought of using detection and though I did get edges, I couldn't fill the gaps so I used contour detection and but they don't work well many many not-so-well-shaped plants with variation in color.

My current method attempts to find green color in HSV colorspace.It's easier to define green colorspace but not for the little brownish tints.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os, glob  

def method_1(img):
    # Blur the image
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(9,9),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    ## convert to hsv
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


    ## mask of green (36,25,25) ~ (86, 255,255)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (85, 255,255))

    ## slice the green
    imask = mask>0
    green = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
    green[imask] = img[imask]


    # apply dilation on src image
    kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)
    dilated_img = cv2.dilate(green, kernel, iterations = 2)


    # Draw contours and fill holes
    canvas = dilated_img.copy() # Canvas for plotting contours on
    canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(canvas, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    return canvas, contours


def get_mask(maskfolder, file_path, filename, savefile):
    contour_list = []

    img = cv2.imread(file_path)
    rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    
    plt.imshow(rgb_img)
    plt.show()
```

It works fine for images which look like:

[image]

but not for images like this:

[image]

Sample results below

[image]
[image]

I then used a simple contouring method

```
def method_2(img):
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(gray,  cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    return gray, contours

def get_mask(maskfolder, file_path, filename, savefile):
    contour_list = []

    img = cv2.imread(file_path)
    rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # METHOD 2
    canvas_2, contours_2 = method_2(rgb_img)
    for cnt in contours_2:
        cv2.drawContours(canvas_2,[cnt],-1,255,-1)

    
    plt.imshow(canvas_2, cmap="gray")
    plt.show()
```

but it returns black images:

[image]

Comment: tried this. too many different different variation of colors to choose from as each image a a different brightness and some have darker brownish tint, some have lesser tint.

Comment: bad lighting. overexposure is a problem. shadows are a problem. _why_ are you trying to segment these?

Comment: I need to computer certain of the plant but then I need to segment the plant first

Comment: @Sulphur you can convert the image to LAB color space and analyse the individual channels. The a channel represents green color and can help segment it

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of varying illumintation by normalizing the colors (divide the RGB components by their sum). Anyway, the saturated areas are forever lost.

The you can classify the background vs. the foreground by the nearest neighbor rule, based on a few colors that you pick. If you need an automated solution, the k-nearest neighbor algorithm can be a start.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the second image, the background is very similar to the plant green color. Will kmeans still be able to segment it?

Comment: @Sulphur: try it.